# Fractional Bochner spaces $H^s((0,\infty); V)$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm looking for "intrinsic" definitions of fractional Bochner spaces such as $H^s((0,\infty); V)$ for a Banach space $V$ and exponent $s \in (0,1)$. I have seen these spaces being defined as interpolation spaces but I want to understand relationships, properties and characterisations of these spaces when they are defined, for example, as the set of functions $f$ such that $t \mapsto \lVert f(t) \rVert_V$ belongs to $H^s(0,\infty)$. Probably they are equivalent. But I would like a reference to study these kinds of spaces more in depth.